# Formal proof for $A \cup (B-A) = A\cup B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am just confused by the whole concept if someone can explain it to me or provide a different example so I can understand this would be much appreciated.

I want to prove that $$A \cup (B-A) = A\cup B$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: The answer below should be enough. Notice also that $(A-B)\cup (B-A)\cup (A\cap B)=A\cup B$ try to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Usually, showing that two sets are equal (say $C=D$), can be undertaken in two steps:

1. Show that $C\subseteq D$ (that is, that every element $c\in C$ satisfies $c\in D$)
2. Show that $D\subseteq C$ (that is, that every element $d\in D$ satisfies $d\in C$.)

This is sufficient to show that the two sets are equal.

So, for your case:

Let $x\in A\cup (B\setminus A)$.  How can you show that $x\in A\cup B$? Start by noting that $x\in A\cup (B\setminus A)$ implies that either $x\in A$ or $x\in B\setminus A$. Can you proceed from there?

If you can do that, then you need to do the reverse: assume you have some $y\in A\cup B$, and prove that $y\in A\cup(B\setminus A)$.

Comment: thanks make sense now.